# how to get Menu item click in nav to fire jquery click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, events

I have a partialview with a Std out of the box Layout and a Partial Menu.
When I click the Anchor element to Login (the idea is to show the Login in a jquery  modal dialog..in a div outside the nav element), the jquery function does not even fire.
Thanks.

```html
<div class="table-responsive" style="z-index:999">
 <nav class="navbar-inverse2" style="text-align:start">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btnLoginYYY">LoginY</a>
  <div class="container-fluid">  
   <ul class="nav navbar-inverse2 navbar-right">
    @if (Session["LoginCredentials"] != null)
    {
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOff", "Account", new { }, new { @Style = "color:Gainsboro" })</li>
    }
    else
    {
     <li>
      <a href="#" class="btnLoginxxx" onclick="LoadDetailPartialView">Login</a>
     </li>
    }
   </ul>
  </div>

  @section Scripts{

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", "#btnLoginYYY", function ()
    {
     alert("here:");
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#btnLoginYYY", function ()
    {
     alert("here2:");
    });

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
     $(function ()
     {
      $("#btnLoginxxx").click(function ()
      {
       alert("click");
      });

      $(document).on("click", "#btnLoginxxx", function ()
      {
       alert("here:");
      });

     });

    });
   </script>
  }
 </nav>
</div>
<div id="dialog2" title="Login View" style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors on your browser console?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function ()
    {` and `$(function ()
     {`...this is the same thing twice. One is just a different way of writing the other. You only need one of them.

Comment: `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js`...why are you using a release-candidate version of jQuery? 1.12 has been released for years, and has several subsequent point releases - use a supported version, 1.12.4 is the latest in the 1.x branch

Answer (score 1):

Your code to handle clicking on the Login button doesn't work because you have no button with the ID `btnLoginxxx`. You've got one with the *class* `buttonLoginxxx` though.

If you have only one login button (which you probably should), the most sensible change would be to change the element to have an ID:

```
<a href="#" id="btnLoginxxx"
```

and then the jQuery will work.

---

N.B. Just for info, to match on the existing class you'd need to use `.btnLoginxxx` as the selector. I don't know if it's just a typo or you don't  understand the difference between and ID and a class, and the selectors which represent them.  If you don't, now's a good time to learn: `#someName` selects a single element by its (unique) ID, whereas `.someClassName` selects an element (or elements, since classes can be applied to multiple elements) by class name.

The full spec is at https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html . jQuery also documents some of that, and provide some of their own extensions, viewable here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the feedback and solution.
I did however have to move my script into the underlying view as for some reason it was not rendering with the Menu/Login nav partial.